# 58.85 displays as 58.84999999999

Tags: floating-point, decimal, calculator, abap

I am building a calculator with BSP.
As I tested it with various numbers, I ran into a problem that the decimal numbers don't display correctly.

For example.
58.85 -> 58.849999. But 58.84 or 58.86 work just fine.
58.8471 -> 54.84710000000001. At the end last typed digit will be saved out of nowhere.

My code following below.

```
method GENERATE_NUM.

  DATA: lv_digi type I.  * number of digits after the decimal point


  call METHOD me->get_decimal
    RECEIVING
      getdigits = lv_digi.

  *if it is a natural number  
  IF lv_digi = 0.
    IF thisnum < 0.
      result = thisnum * 10 - newdigit.
    ELSE.
      result = thisnum * 10 + newdigit.
    ENDIF.

   *if it is a float number
   Else.
    IF thisnum < 0.
      result = thisnum - ( newdigit / 10 ** lv_digi ).
    ELSE.
      result = thisnum + ( newdigit / 10 ** lv_digi ).
    ENDIF.

    *increase the number of decimal point by 1
    call method me->set_decimal.
  ENDif.

endmethod.
```

What I basically do is everytime a number is clicked, it calls the "generate_num" method.
It takes THISNUM, NEWDIGIT, RESULT as parameters.

 thisnum = current number (eg:58.8)

 newdigit = clicked number (eg: 5)

 result = generated number (expected: 58.85 but returns 58.849999).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: It would be helpful if you illustrate where and how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's one of those commonly asked questions that needs a very long explanation. I'll let someone else step in or find a suitable duplicate to close as.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want decimal numbers with fixed precision, you should use the type P (packed number) instead of float.

Example:

```
DATA lv_fixed_point TYPE p LENGTH 16 DECIMALS 2.
```

This creates a fixed-point variable with two digits after the point. The exact meaning of the "length" parameter isn't that straight-forward. From the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/fc/eb2fd9358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm):

> Packed numbers - type P
>
> Type P data allows digits after the decimal point. The number of
>   decimal places is generic, and is determined in the program. The value
>   range of type P data depends on its size and the number of digits
>   after the decimal point. The valid size can be any value from 1 to 16
>   bytes. Two decimal digits are packed into one byte, while the last
>   byte contains one digit and the sign. Up to 14 digits are allowed
>   after the decimal point. The initial value is zero. When working with
>   type P data, it is a good idea to set the program attribute Fixed
>   point arithmetic.Otherwise, type P numbers are treated as integers.
>
> You can use type P data for such values as distances, weights, amounts
>   of money, and so on.

Comment: simply changing the type to p solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can call `CALL FUNCTION 'FLOATINGPOINT_COMPARE_ABSOLUTE'` to factor in IEEE float epsilons. Working with floating point you should actually avoid using comparisons directly, and write your own with built-in epsilons:

```
 IS_EQUAL
 IS_GREATER
 IS_GREATER_EQUAL
 IS_LESS
 IS_LESS_EQUAL
```

are the bare minimum.

More reading [about floating point here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Learn it. Live it. Love it.

As a non-trivial exercise you can also read up on `NaN` `+Inf` and `-Inf` (Also sNAN if you working with other `DECFLOAT` types instead of `f`).

Comment: But packed can be the optimal solution (but not as fast since they are still interpreted as CHAR-kinda) with the least about of hurdles.